# Woocommerce not sending Emails on cancelled order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem: my woocommerce won't send emails when I cancel an order, though the recipients is

```
{customer_email}
```

in the WC Email Settings.

I also tried adding my own mail address but it doesn't work too.

Furthermore I wonder why all other mails work..

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you leave it blank? Does it send it to the default email address?

Comment: Oh boy didn't think of this and yes it does send it my admin mail is my customer mail variable wrong?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if you can actually send a cancellation email to your customer via the admin area, what you can do is add a hook in for the cancellation email https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html and either add an additional email to it or replace the email address its being sent to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in your site's theme's functions.php:

```
/* 
 * Add customer email to Cancelled Order recipient list
 */
 function wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email( $recipient, $order ){
     return $recipient . ',' . $order->billing_email;
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I cannot believe there is not a simple checkbox in woocommerce for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email( $recipient, $order )
{ 
 return $recipient . ',' . $order->billing_email; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_order', 'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_failed_order', 'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Please add some description to make others understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this plugin to send emails on cancellation (and other events)

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woo-custom-emails/